# Hi , I am learning flutter , my question is what does application domain or app id do?

Tags: flutter, dart

what is exactly its job? can't I upload my app to stores without them?
when I created my flutter app I didn't give it a domain so when I searched for it in the app
my app id was like com. example.the app name, what that mean?
thank u.

Answer (score 1):

The application id is an ID that uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store.

There is a lot to consider when releasing an app. Most, if not all, information is available here:

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/ios